# Creating NFC Reader application

Tags: android, nfc

I want to develop a NFC tag reader application.  I have some knowledge about the NFC API in the Android SDK.  I have even imported the NFCDemo sample app from the Android SDK sample apps.  The NFCDemo app just creates fake tags and capture them.  I want to recognize NFC tags when they are tapped on the back of phone. I have a Google Nexus Phone to test this.

My question is, when I tap a tag on the back of the phone, the "ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED" intent is dispatched ... How and where this intent is to be handled?  How is "ForegroundDispatch" used for the same?

Thanking in anticipation,
Shivdattam.

Answer (score 2):

Check `TagViewer.java` class in `NFCDemo` app (http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NFCDemo/src/com/example/android/nfc/TagViewer.html). It will give solution for your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is "the Intent ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED" is fired automatically or is to be fired by yourself after tag is touched on the back of your phone.Is it?

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [Android boilerplate project](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/downloads/detail?name=ndeftools-boilerplate-1.0.zip&can=2&q=#makechanges) you might be interested in, it seems to cover what you are looking for.